# Integral using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to compute the following integral using complex analysis tools:

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{i\theta}} \, d\theta.
$$

It was suggested to me to use the substitution $z = e^{i\theta}$, but that results in $dz = ie^{i\theta}$ and I don't see how everything can be substituted in to convert to $z$.

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 13):

If you substitute $z = e^{i\theta}$, then you get $dz = ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta = iz\,d\theta$, and so $d\theta = \dfrac{dz}{iz}$.

Then, we get $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{e^{i\theta}}\,d\theta = \oint_{|z| = 1}\dfrac{e^z}{iz}\,dz$, which is easy if you know [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula).

Answer (score 4):

The value of the integral is just $2\pi$. This happens because:
$$e^{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
and 
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{mi\theta}d\theta$$
equals zero for any integer $m$, except $m=0$.